# Estimating the Cost of Creating an Image Dataset like GQA and Relevant Sources

Tags: nlp, dataset, computer-vision

I am currently working on a project that requires an extensive image dataset, similar to the [GQA](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/dorarad/gqa/about.html) dataset. I am in the early stages of planning and would like to get an estimate of the cost involved in creating such a dataset. The GQA dataset is known for its diverse set of images annotated with questions and answers, making it a valuable resource for various computer vision tasks.

I would appreciate insights from the community on the following:

1. **Cost Estimate:** Can anyone provide an estimate of the cost involved in creating an image dataset like GQA? This could include expenses related to image acquisition, annotation, and any other relevant factors.
2. **Breakdown of Costs:** If possible, could there be any breakdown of the costs involved in each phase of dataset creation? For instance, costs associated with obtaining high-quality images, hiring annotators, or any other significant expenses.
3. **Relevant Sources:** Are there any reputable sources or case studies that discuss the costs associated with creating image datasets for computer vision tasks? I'm looking for insights that can help in better understanding the financial aspects of such projects.

I understand that the costs may vary depending on several factors, but any ballpark figures or general advice on budgeting for such projects would be incredibly helpful!